# List of objects with a list as a property of the object

Tags: c#, string, list, object

Declaring a list of objects:

```
List<object> result = new List<object>();
```

and a list of int to store the ids:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
```

I want to store in `result` objects containing the pair `(string, list of int)`.

It works fine for the pair `(string, int)` but I want that when there are 2 identical strings to have only one object and the int values to be stored in a list.

ex: `{pars = "xxx", id = 1} , {pars = "xxx", id = 2}` becomes `{pars = "xxx", id = (1,2 )}`

For doing the initial functionality, I use a `foreach` through an object from which I take the string(pars) and the id:

```
    foreach (dataBinding in myData)
    {
        var x = string.Join(" ", dataBinding.Params.Select(p => p.myDescription));

        result.Add(new { pars = x, id = dataBinding.Id });

    }
```

there could be more strings in `Params`, that's why I use the join.

As it is here it works by creating objects having the form `(string, int)`. But my aim is to make it `(string, list of int)` and if there are two objects with same string to combine them as I wrote before.

I tried to add `ids` list as the second property of the object but probably I'm not doing it correctly.

```
 result.Add(new { pars = x, ids = dataBinding.Id });
```

Comment: Have you considered using Dictionary?

Comment: [`Lookup<string, int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better fit, you can use [`Enumerable.ToLookup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method over your `myData` variable.

Comment: Use Dictionary<string, List<int>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ, especially `GroupBy`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> descriptionIDs = myData
    .GroupBy(x => x.myDescription)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.Id).ToList());
```

Now you have even a dictionary, not just a strange `List<object>` that contains anonymous types.

As someone mentioned, you can also use `ToLookup` which i'd also prefer:

```
var descriptionLookup = myData.ToLookup(x => x.myDescription);
```

Now you can get the ID-List easily:

```
var result = descriptionLookup.Select(g => new { pars = g.Key, ids = g.Select(x=> x.Id).ToList() }).ToList():
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am not understanding the scenario fully but I suspect using the following would server your purpose.

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>
```

When the key doesn't exist you add it and when it does you just add to the List.

Answer (score 1):

Below program depicts the current generic collection type, also allow to add a new value if Key Already exists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        MyProgram p = new MyProgram();
        
        p.Add("First" , 5);
        p.Add("Second" , 8);
        p.Add("Third" , 9);
        p.Add("First" , 6);
        p.Add("First" , 7);
        
        p.PrintDictionary();
    }
}


public class MyProgram
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    
    public void Add(string key, int value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key].Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(key, new List<int>() {value});
        }
    }
    
    public void PrintDictionary()
    {
        foreach(var keyValue in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key : " + keyValue.Key);
            
            foreach(var val in keyValue.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\t Value : {0}", val));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

> Key : First
>
> ```
> Value : 5
>
> Value : 6
>
> Value : 7
> ```
>
> Key : Second
>
> ```
> Value : 8
> ```
>
> Key : Third
>
> ```
> Value : 9
> ```

Check this [Live Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WcP8Yz).